# Производительность WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, производительность

Накладываю на вращающийся куб простой textbox. Как только начинаю набирать в нем текст, начинаются приостановки куба, когда мерцает курсор. Что делать, подскажите!

Система XP 2 ГГц, 256 Мб видео внешняя. Пример из SDK, но вместо кнопки вставлен textbox. Как разделить на графические потоки?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, 1) параметры системы, на которой выполняется приложение, 2) отрывок XAML, где происходит наложение элементов. Так вопрос будет понятнее.

Comment: Какой пример из SDK взят (название)?

Answer (score 1):

Я не думаю, что для WPF сложно одновременно вращать куб и набирать текст. Поэтому специальное разделение на потоки вряд ли понадобится.

Чтобы проверить, что c WPF все в порядке, идем в [галерею примеров](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples) для WPF и загружаем пример [3D Hit Testing Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7758). Изменяем этот пример, добавляя поле текстового ввода. Запускаем, наблюдая, как вращается куб, набираем текст и видим, что приостановок куба не наблюдается.

Графика: встроенная в набор Intel 965 Express.

Comment: Да, сейчас действительно все работает хорошо. Скорее всего, это было из-за моего компьютера, который не запустил Hardware shader pixel acceleration в версии .NET3.5 без сервис пака 1. Сейчас в Visual Studio 2010 все отлично работает.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, если отрисовка одной графики требует значительных ресурсов и пересекается с отрисовкой другой графики, их можно разнести по разным потокам. Касательно производительности: WPF поддерживает аппаратное ускорение и должно работать быстро. Подробнее по теме - раздел [производительность](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970776.aspx) (.NET Framework 4) из MSDN.